# In gatsby-ssr file I am not getting empty values of helmet and it is not set by setHeadComponents correctly on priority

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, amazon-cloudfront

In gatsby-ssr I want to set meta tag as first so it is recognize by facebook, twitter. I write below code but in toString() and toComponent() values are returning null.

Code

```
const { Helmet } = require('react-helmet');

exports.onRenderBody = ({
  setHeadComponents,
  setHtmlAttributes,
  setBodyAttributes,
}) => {
  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
  console.log('helmet', helmet);
  setHtmlAttributes(helmet.htmlAttributes.toComponent());
  setBodyAttributes(helmet.bodyAttributes.toComponent());
  setHeadComponents([
    helmet.meta.toComponent(),
    helmet.title.toComponent(),
    helmet.link.toComponent(),
    helmet.noscript.toComponent(),
    helmet.script.toComponent(),
    helmet.style.toComponent(),
  ]);
};

exports.onPreRenderHTML = ({ getHeadComponents, replaceHeadComponents }) => {
  const headComponents = getHeadComponents();
  const metaComponents = [];
  headComponents.map((component) => {
    if (component.type === 'meta') {
      metaComponents.push(component);
    }
    return component;
  });
  const newHeadComponents = [...metaComponents];
  headComponents.map((component) => {
    if (component.type !== 'meta') {
      newHeadComponents.push(component);
    }
    return component;
  });
  replaceHeadComponents(newHeadComponents);
};
```

When I check its console value it is ==>

```
helmet {
  base: {
    toComponent: [Function: toComponent],
    toString: [Function: toString]
  },
  bodyAttributes: {
    toComponent: [Function: toComponent],
    toString: [Function: toString]
  },
  htmlAttributes: {
    toComponent: [Function: toComponent],
    toString: [Function: toString]
  },
  link: {
    toComponent: [Function: toComponent],
    toString: [Function: toString]
  },
  meta: {
    toComponent: [Function: toComponent],
    toString: [Function: toString]
  },
  noscript: {
    toComponent: [Function: toComponent],
    toString: [Function: toString]
  },
  script: {
    toComponent: [Function: toComponent],
    toString: [Function: toString]
  },
  style: {
    toComponent: [Function: toComponent],
    toString: [Function: toString]
  },
  title: {
    toComponent: [Function: toComponent],
    toString: [Function: toString]
  }
}
```

It is not giving results. I want all meta tags on first priority on  section.
when I print console.log(helmet.meta.toString) It will print null string.

Comment: Have you tried using `gatsby build` or `gatsby develop`? It will only work using the first one

Comment: Yes tried with that but not getting results